# Java FX package standard

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to know if there any package standards for java FX applications because when I deploy my application, throws me several error like fxml location not found, didn't find the database, etc. I'm using jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

It is probably you didn't setup your fxml file paths and/or database file path correctly.

If your java class and related fxml files are in the same folder you can just call them like:

**Controller.java**

```
new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ControllerLayout.fxml"));
```

**ControllerLayout.fxml**

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
```

Let's say you have your layouts in **layouts** folder and controllers in parent folder names **main**. Then it should look like this:

**Controller.java**

```
new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layouts/ControllerLayout.fxml"));
```

**ControllerLayout.fxml**

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.Controller">
```

Same thing goes for your database file. But since you couldn't put your db file inside your runnable jar, you must get db path dynamically.

Run this code in your main class to get the absolute path on runtime.

```
public class Main extends Application 
{
   public static String PATH;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Path p = Paths.get(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
        Path folder = p.getParent();
        PATH = folder.toString();     
    }
}
```

Let's assume you put your database file inside a folder named "db". Call this line to get the absolute path of your database

```
String dbpath = "jdbc:sqlite:" + Main.PATH + "/db/mydatabase.db";
```

Comment: When I run the program in the IDE it runs well, but when I create the jar, it give me null pointer exception location is required with the fxml files

Comment: This help me a lot. But didn't work with the database.  The cmd says that 'rsrc' is not installed

Comment: Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Now the jar runs but now it throws null pointer exception to the methods of the program. I don't know what to do

Comment: What library are you using for database? I suggest you to check "sqlite jdbc" library. Where is your db file located after you extracted a jar file? You haven't give much information. I can only assume with what is given.